# Remove and create dir in python not working

Tags: python, distutils, shutil

I have a really simple script:

```
for i in range(2):
    data_folder = os.path.join('.', 'data')

    if os.path.isdir(data_folder):
        rmtree(data_folder)

    distutils.dir_util.mkpath(data_folder, verbose=True)
```

For my knowledge, this should delete the 'data' folder if it exists, then, create it again. Twice.

But, it looks like it has some "cool down" after the folder removal, because the folder is not created after the second time.

I couldn't find anything about it on the documentation or online.

Can anyone help me explaining what's happening and what I can do to avoid it (aka, creating the folder and let it "created" at the end of the script)?

Comment: There isn't any cool down period. If you're not getting an error, it should create the directory.

Comment: It doesn't. Python 3.7. Tested in different Windows machines

Comment: I have had problems on Windows when wanting to delete a possibly populated directory tree (from a previous run) then recreating the folder. Had to add a check after the ‘delete’ using `rmtree` waiting until the top-level folder doesn’t exist before recreating it.

Comment: I tried this on Mac OS. I don't have 3.7.3, so I used `os.makedirs` instead of distutils.dir_util.mkpath`. But it worked.

Comment: With `os.makedirs` it indeed works, which is weird. Anyway, thank you

Comment: I would tip on the deleted dirs still being returned as available when `mkpath` is invoked; try adding `assert os.path.isdir(data_folder)` after `shutil.rmtree` call and check whether the assertion fails.